# Error message "Forbidden you don't have permission to access this resource "

Tags: django, apache, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-22.04

I want to deploy a django app using ubuntu 22.04 as a wsl package on windows laptop and i am using an ec2 instance to host, i've made all configurations and settings but when i try to access the website on chrome using it's public IP i get error "Forbidden, you don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at 54.81.101.238 Port 80

I've tried different solutions found online, even the ones found on stackoverflow
i've given apache permissions to my app folder, made various changes to my apache2.conf and virtualhost file but i still get the same error

my virtualhost conf file:
<VirtualHost *:80>

```
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/rotisary/postly

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/rotisary/postly/static
    <Directory /home/rotisary/postly/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/rotisary/postly/media
    <Directory /home/rotisary/postly/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/rotisary/postly/postly>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rotisary/postly/postly/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/rotisary/postly:/home>        WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

apache has access to all my folders, from the root directory (home) to the directory of my django app

Comment: Is your EC2 in a public subnet? Are the security groups opened? Can you share the startup logs generated by your app? When running on your EC2, did you changed the IP address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: thanks,but I already closed that instance and created a new instance and started deployment all over again,now the error is gone, i probably made a mistake when i was deploying the first time...now what i'm faced with is an internal server error, any help regarding that ?

Comment: @OladotunKolapo you shoud open a new question regarding your server error